# Need to add an onClick Listener to this code to call a another activity

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

```
if (item.getUrl() != null) {
    url.setText(Html.fromHtml("<a href=\"" + item.getUrl() + "\">"
            + "Click to View "+ item.getName() + "</a> "));

    // Making url clickable
    url.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    url.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

} else {
    // url is null, remove from the view
    url.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

I'm trying to change this from clickable text that opens the web browser to one that opens a webview. The problem I'm having is putting an OnClickListener in this code.  I just want to send the url to the webview activity upon clicking he text.

Here's my webViewActivity:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;

 public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView webView;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_webview);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl(this.getIntent().getDataString());

    }

}
```

Comment: Can we see your best attempt? Do you know how to start another activity from the existing one?

Comment: So add a listener then, and don't make it an HTML anchor.

Comment: I just left the html anchor in there to show I had a getUrl() method available.  I plan to change that to "Click to View " + item.getname (). My problem is making the onclicklistener and the intent to call the activity.

Comment: I'm not clear with your question. You want to open browser in Activity B when you click on Text in Actvity A?

Comment: No, I want to open the url in a webview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started by taking out this line
url.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

Added this where it was:

```
url.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    startWeb(item.getUrl());
                }
            });
```

and this to pass the url to the webView

```
public void startWeb(String url) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(activity.getBaseContext(),
            WebViewActivity.class);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
    this.activity.startActivity(intent);
}
```